# How to pass data stored in table between test pages in fitnesse

Tags: .net, testing, fitnesse, fixture

In my fitnesse project i've got one table which stores authentication data to database. I'm using it on each site. Is it possible to have one site with that table and allow all other test sites use data from it? how i can define global table with variables that i need?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Site'? Do you mean an individual asp.net page? Or do you mean different asp.net projects/applications/assemblies?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a procedure in your SuiteSetUp and re-use it on multiple pages. http://fitsharp.github.com/Fit/DefineFixture.html